# Set edge length with circle layout in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

Using cytoscape.js how to set the length of all edges in graph having 'circle' layout as well as with 'grid' layout?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In general, that's not possible for a grid nor a circle.  You may achieve something similar with the concentric layout with appropriately set levels.